# I can not access the HTML in a given CMS, right?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I work in wordpress but do have some clue about HTML. So now I know it is easy to use custom CSS but I d like to change something in the HTML. And ideas, suggestions ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't directly change themes (HTML/CSS) since when the theme is about to get updated, your custom HTML and CSS will be reset (deleted). If you want to edit a WordPress theme, you  need to create a child theme.

1. Create a child theme that's called similarly to your parent theme (twentyfeefteen-child)
2. Create a `style.css` file inside the newly created folder
3. Type in the following:

   ```
   /*
   Theme Name:   Twenty Fifteen Child
   Description:  Twenty Fifteen Child Theme
   Template:     twentyfifteen
   Version:      1.0.0
   Text Domain:  twenty-fifteen-child
   */
   ```
4. Now you simply create files you want to overrite. Say you want to edit the `index.php`page. You create a file called `index.php` in the child theme folder, copy the code from the parent and edit what you want.

Templates are usually located in: `{your project path}/wp-content/themes/`

For more info about child themes, go [here...](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)